# SDL_PollEvent seems to prevent window surface from updating

Tags: c++, sdl, sdl-2

I'm currently walking through the Lazy Foo tutorials for SDL2 (I'm doing this on a Linux machine) and I'm encountering some kind of bug where the inclusion of `SDL_PollEvent` in my main loop seems to prevent `SDL_UpdateWindowSurface` from actually updating. If I leave the `SDL_PollEvent` loop out, the loaded bmp displays properly. However, if I include the `SDL_PollEvent` loop or even a call to `SDL_PollEvent`, then the window never gets updated with an image. Everything else seems to work fine, `SDL_PollEvent` is queuing events properly and the loop handles the events properly, but for some reason there's a visual discrepancy between the inclusion of `SDL_PollEvent` vs. leaving it out.

Using the code provided by [Lesson 03: Event driven programming](http://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/03_event_driven_programming/index.php):

This loop fails to update the window:

```
while( !quit )
{
  //Handle events on queue
  while( SDL_PollEvent( &e ) != 0 )
  {
    //User requests quit
    if( e.type == SDL_QUIT )
    {
      quit = true;
    }
  }

  //Apply the image
  SDL_BlitSurface( gXOut, NULL, gScreenSurface, NULL );

  //Update the surface
  SDL_UpdateWindowSurface( gWindow );
}
```

This loop successfully updates the window with the loaded image:

```
while( !quit )
{

  //Apply the image
  SDL_BlitSurface( gXOut, NULL, gScreenSurface, NULL );

  //Update the surface
  SDL_UpdateWindowSurface( gWindow );
}
```

But it stops working with the inclusion of a single call to `SDL_PollEvent`:

```
while( !quit )
{
  SDL_PollEvent(&e);

  //Apply the image
  SDL_BlitSurface( gXOut, NULL, gScreenSurface, NULL );

  //Update the surface
  SDL_UpdateWindowSurface( gWindow );
}
```

Comment: Are you declaring `e`? Is there a `SDL_Event e;` somewhere?

Comment: Also are you calling SDL_PollEvent in the correct thread? From the docs: "As this function implicitly calls SDL_PumpEvents(), you can only call this function in the thread that set the video mode." https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_PollEvent

Comment: Yes, aside from the code I'm displaying above, the rest of the code is left the same as the code used in the tutorial, which can be downloaded from the page.

Comment: Also, it's not an issue of `SDL_Event` not working itself, it picks up events fine and I can handle them if I want. And there's no multi-threading code in the tutorial, so that edge case of SDL shouldn't be a problem here. The problem is that I seem not to be able to include `SDL_Event` without effecting whether the image gets successfully displayed in the window.

Comment: Try calling `SDL_BlitSurface` and `SDL_UpdateWindowSurface` above where you start the `SDL_PollEvent` loop

Comment: Then it will update properly once and never again. If I were to call them again, which I do in a loop, the window would not get updated after `SDL_PollEvent` has been called. Making that change in Lesson 4, for example, would simply result in the initial window being displayed properly, but no window update would successfully happen after `SDL_PollEvent`, which it should.

Comment: @oldmanmike there may be a resize event that invalidates window surface. Get window surface after event loop but just before blitting.

Comment: That works, thank you! Post it below and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[SDL_GetWindowSurface documentation](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_GetWindowSurface) says `This surface will be invalidated if the window is resized`. Upon initial window creation several events are generated, like `SDL_WINDOWEVENT_SHOWN` and `SDL_WINDOWEVENT_EXPOSED`. While window isn't marked as user-resizable, I suppose window manager still have an ability to perform resize; you may want to check which events are placed in your event queue (as I cannot reproduce your problem - may be e.g. window manager specific).

To put it in other worlds, window surface isn't guaranteed to persist after some events, so theoretically flushing event queue can invalidate surface. You need to get window surface after flushing event queue just before drawing, on each frame:

```
while( !quit )
{
  // event loop here

  // get surface to draw on
  gScreenSurface = SDL_GetWindowSurface(gWindow);

  //Apply the image
  SDL_BlitSurface( gXOut, NULL, gScreenSurface, NULL );

  //Update the surface
  SDL_UpdateWindowSurface( gWindow );
}
```